# Apply a unary transformer to a linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list, unary-function

I've been working on a practice problem. The idea is that I'm supposed to take a linked list, then apply a unary transformer to the list, and return the modified list. I'm not applying a specific change, just process and return a linked list. Here's the breakdown, along with the UnaryTransformer method provided by the instructions:

"If L is the head of a linked list of objects of the type
Q and R is a UnaryTransformer, then transformAll(L,R) is the linked list of objects obtained by applying R to every
object in L in order."

```
{@code UnaryTransformer} objects are used to represent functions with the signature:
```

[image]

```
public interface UnaryTransformer<Q> {
      /**
       * Returns the result of applying a function modeled by
       * {@code UnaryTransformer} to the given object
       *
       * @param object the object to transform
       * @return the result of applying a function
       */
    Q apply(Q object);
}
```

So far I have this code, but it doesn't compile.

```
public static transformAll(Node L, R) {
    if (L != null) {
    LinkedList<Q> sequence = new LinkedList<Q>();

    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        if (p.apply(get(i))){
            sequence.add(get(i));
            }
        }
return sequence;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndyTurner You probably mean `replaceAll(UnaryOperator<E> operator)`?

Comment: @lexicore I did.

Comment: Something like that, but the replaceAll only works on ArrayLists, not LinkedLists. For example, if I had a LinkedList of even numbers and wanted to divide each value by 2, the transform method would run the list through the transformer and return the modified list

Comment: What do you think, the method's signature shall do: `transformAll(Node L, R)`? What is `R`? Reads like a type, but `L` is a parameter name. By the way: It should be written lowercase.

Comment: @009 [`replaceAll` is defined on the `List` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-). It is supported by `LinkedList` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close!  Assuming your `get` method returns an element of the `LinkedList` at index `i`, calling it twice would return the same element regardless if it was mapped.  You should pass the result of `R.apply` directly to the new `LinkedList` to assure that it **is** mapped:

```
public LinkedList<Q> transformAll(Node L, UnaryTransformer<Q> R) {
    if (L == null) {
        return null;
    }

    LinkedList<Q> sequence = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        sequence.add(R.apply(get(i)));
    }

    return sequence;
}
```

Keep in mind that `get` for `LinkedList` is an `O(n)` operation, so this method is `O(n^2)`.  It can be mitigated by simply iterating over the `LinkedList` directly.

**Note**: This assumes that this method is located within your `LinkedList` class and `Q` is the generic type of the list.

Comment: Thanks, I keep looking at the questions and try to make the name exactly as it appears in the instructions.